# NSURLRequest the request time out

Tags: objective-c, json, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest, request-timed-out

I've a strange problem, I'm working on a project that I've to request from a server, When requesting a `URL` without parameters using `GET` method, it works fine and return the desired data, but when using the same code to call the `URL` and sending a parameters to it, it fail with this error:

```
error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 UserInfo=0xed4870 "timed out"
```

My code is the following:

```
NSString *param = @"pageNumber=2";

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myWebsite/api/Soccor/"];//When using this, it works fine
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://myWebsite/api/Soccor?%@", param]];//When using this, it gives me the request time out error.
NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[theRequest addValue:@"application/json;charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[theRequest addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[theRequest addValue:msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[theRequest setTimeoutInterval:10];
NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
```

Any clue why it returns error when sending parameters with the `URL`?

Comment: Once check your url format While passing parameters you may need to give any key for that param value.

Comment: @kalyanipuvvada Could you please explain more !? Your comment is not clear to me.

Comment: @Rob I've tested the URL in the browser and it's working fine, that's the weirdest part. Regarding your point on the headers, why it works with the first URL, but the second doesn't !?

Comment: @Rob It seems you are right, the problem is `Content-Length`, When I've removed it, it works fine. Please answer the question so I accept it. But how come That error appear, if you have any explanation please tell me.

Comment: @Scar In terms of why precisely it behaves precisely the way it does when you send a malformed request, I don't know. I'd suspect that it depends upon what you set `msgLength` to (you never showed us that) and how your server is configured (I wouldn't be surprised to see different servers respond differently to these sorts of error conditions).

Comment: @Rob I've another issue, When requesting a URL with the following `http://myWebSite/api/soccor/10165`it suppose to return the soccor details, I've tested it on PostMan client (Chrome) it works fine, between, in the objective-c it does not work, do you have any idea why these things happen?

Comment: @Rob I've check the response, it's empty, when calling any service, it works fine and the response method `didReceiveData` is called probably, but in this service, this method is not called at all, it goes directly to `connectionDidFinishLoading` with empty respond. I will keep testing it and if I still have this error, I will ask another question, thank you for your assist :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you consider two aspects of the request:

1. You are not showing us your setting of `msgLength`, but I would only suggest setting a `Content-Length` header if you're also using `setHTTPBody`, in which case you'd set the `Content-Length` to be the `length` of the `NSData` you use as a parameter to `setHTTPBody`. But this is used with `POST` requests, not `GET` requests.
2. You specify `application/json` for the `Content-Type` of the request, but request does not consist of JSON. If you did that because the response is JSON, it should be noted that this header value is for your request, not for the response you expect from the server.